# Model.all or Self.all in Model function to get all records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

This is the function in the **model**.

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  def self.to_all
    cars = Car.all  # first way
    cars = Self.all # second way
  end
end
```

Which is the correct?

Comment: What's `Self` there?

Comment: There's more to the `to_all` method that you're not showing us, right? Otherwise, what's the point?

Answer (score 0):

Neither.

> When class (or module) methods call other such methods, omit the use
>   of a leading self or own name followed by a . when calling other such
>   methods. This is often seen in "service classes" or other similar
>   concepts where a class is treated as though it were a function. This
>   convention tends to reduce repetitive boilerplate in such classes.
>   - [The Ruby Style Guide.](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#namespace-definition)

```
class TestClass
  # bad -- more work when class renamed/method moved
  def self.call(param1, param2)
    TestClass.new(param1).call(param2)
  end

  # bad -- more verbose than necessary
  def self.call(param1, param2)
    self.new(param1).call(param2)
  end

  # good
  def self.call(param1, param2)
    new(param1).call(param2)
  end

  # ...other methods...
end
```

Additionally `Self.all` will give you `NameError (uninitialized constant Self)`. Keywords are always lowercase in Ruby.